# delete multiple AD groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to delete multiple AD group using powershell. All the groups are in a .txt or .csv file. I tried to use this command but it's not working properly.

```
get-content c:\test\groups.csv | remove-adgroup
```

Do you have any ideeas?

Comment: I assume you get some kind of error message?

Comment: Hello, before i tested the above command but not working properly because i put the groups in a txt file. Now i tested with a csv file and the powershell run with admin rights and everithing is working properly :)

Comment: To use a (proper) csv file, use `Import-Csv`, not `Get-Content`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this. This script provides clean csv import and understandable iteration of your data.

```
#Import CSV
$adgroups = Import-Csv "c:\test\groups.csv"

#Iterate trough your List
foreach ($group in $adgroups) {
  try {#try/catch for some sort of error handling
   Remove-ADGroup -Identity $group.Name ##.Name if your CSV column is named "Name"
   Write-Host "$group was successfully removed"
  }catch {
   Write-Host "$group wasnt removed"
 }

}
```